# Печать из HTA (HTML-приложения)

Tags: html, asp.net, html-application

Вопрос в следующем: Имеется веб-приложение (ASP.NET) на веб-сервере, там происходит определенный расчет.

Имеется приложение kiosk.hta, которое находится на киоске (терминале) и запускает  asp-приложение таким образом:

```
workarea.location="http://somedomain.ru/kiosk/CalcPage.aspx"
```

В ASP приложении есть функция вывода на печать документа. Но при попытке напечатать, возможно выбрать только принтеры установленные на веб-сервере, а не на киоске.

Как реализовать печать через принтер, подключенный напрямую к киоску?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как сказано в статье ["How Can I Print Just the Text Area of an HTA?"](https://web.archive.org/web/20150405014735/http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/04/27/how-can-i-print-just-the-text-area-of-an-hta.aspx) попробуйте вызвать InvokeVerbEx("Print").

> ### How Can I Print Just the Text Area of an HTA?
>
> Hey, Scripting Guy! I have an HTA where information gets written to a
> text area. How can I print just the information found in that text
> area?
>
> Hey, DS. We want you to level with us here: are the Scripting Guys
> dead? We ask that because we saw the movie The Sixth Sense a few years
> ago and we understand how this life/death thing works. If you’re
> familiar with The Sixth Sense, you’ll recall that there were all these
> eerie happenings and coincidences which could only be explained by one
> thing: the protagonist (Bruce Willis) was dead. That made for a nifty
> little movie, only now we Scripting Guys seem to be involved with a
> bunch of eerie happenings ourselves; after all, in the span of three
> days we received two emails from people asking these very same
> question: how can I print just the text area of an HTML Application
> (HTA)? Coincidence? Let’s hope so; otherwise there can be only one
> explanation: the Scripting Guys are dead.
>
> Note. Hey, don’t worry about us. After all, one of the nice things
> about being a Scripting Guy is that it doesn’t matter much whether
> we’re dead or alive: our days go pretty much the same either way.
>
> Of course, the premise of The Sixth Sense is that even though Bruce
> Willis was dead he refused to acknowledge it. Taking a page from
> Bruce’s book, we’ve decided to go ahead and answer your question as if
> we were are still alive, too. And we were able to come up with an
> answer for you, even if it was somewhat less-than-elegant. For some
> reason we had the notion that there was a very straightforward way to
> print just the information found in a text area, but when we went
> looking for that answer we couldn’t find it. After a brief but
> fruitless search we gave up and came up with a workaround that
> accomplishes the same thing. (And, yes, had we been alive we might
> have had the energy to search a little harder. But we suppose you have
> to expect some drawbacks to being dead.)
>
> At any rate, here’s a very simple HTA that contains just two items: a
> text area named DataArea and a button labeled Print. Any time you
> click the Print button the HTA saves the information in the text area
> to a temporary file and then uses the Shell.Application object to
> print that file. Here’s what the HTA code looks like:
>
> ```
> <html>
> <head>
> <title>HTA Test</title>
> <HTA:APPLICATION 
>      ID="objTest" 
>      APPLICATIONNAME="HTA Test"
>      SCROLL="yes"
>      SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
> >
> </head>
>
> <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
>
>     Sub PrintText
>         strText = DataArea.Value
>
>         Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>         strFileName = "temporary_print_file.txt"
>         Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFileName)
>         objFile.Write strText
>         objFile.Close
>
>         Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFileName)
>         strPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
>
>         Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
>         Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strPath) 
>         Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(strFileName)
>         objFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
>
>     End Sub
>
> </SCRIPT>
>
> <body>
>     <textarea name="DataArea" rows=5 cols=70></textarea><p>
>     <input id=runbutton  type="button" value="Print" name="run_button" onClick="PrintText">
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Note. Before we begin explaining how this all works we should note
> that we won’t discuss the code involved in creating the HTA itself;
> our focus will be solely on the script that prints the information
> found in the text area. If you need some background information on
> creating HTAs then you might check out our HTA Developer’s Center.
>
> So how do we print the information found in the text area? Well, we
> start by grabbing the information found in the text area and storing
> it in a variable named strText:
>
> ```
> strText = DataArea.Value
> ```
>
> After we’ve done that we encounter a block of code that creates an
> instance of the FileSystemObject and provides a file name
> (temporary_print_file.txt) for our temporary print file. We then call
> the CreateTextFile method to create this file (by default it will be
> created in the same folder as the HTA itself). As soon as the file has
> been created we call the Write method to write the value of strText to
> the file, then close the file. All that takes place here:
>
> ```
> Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
> strFileName = "temporary_print_file.txt"
> Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFileName)
> objFile.Write strText
> objFile.Close
> ```
>
> What did that gain us? Well, we’ve now taken all the information found
> in the text area and saved it to a separate text file. That means
> that, in order to print just the information in the text area, we
> don’t have to do anything any more complicated than simply printing
> the text file. And that’s what we do here:
>
> ```
> Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFileName)
> strPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
>
> Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
> Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strPath) 
> Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(strFileName)
> objFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
> ```
>
> Yes, that looks a tiny bit complicated, but that’s primarily because
> of the eccentricities of the Shell object: in particular, the Shell
> object requires us to take a slightly roundabout path before we can
> bind to - and then print - the file. But don’t let the looks deceive
> you: if you’ve seen The Sixth Sense then you know that things aren’t
> always what they seem.
>
> In other words, we first use the GetFile method to bind the
> FileSystemObject to our temporary file. After that we call the
> GetParentFolderName method to determine the path to the folder where
> the temporary file lives (for example, if our temporary file is named
> C:\Scripts\temporary_print_file.txt then the parent folder will be
> C:\Scripts). That’s what the first two lines of code do:
>
> ```
> Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFileName)
> strPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
> ```
>
> Once the folder path is stashed away in the variable strPath we can
> then create the Shell.Application object and use the Namespace method
> to bind to the folder. In turn, we can call the ParseName method on
> that folder, passing as the sole parameter the variable strFileName
> (which is storing the name of the temporary file for us). That’s
> somewhat-goofy syntax, but the net result is that by binding to a
> folder and then passing ParseName the name of a file within that
> folder we get a FolderItem object pointing directly to our text file.
> Is that good? You bet it is: once the Shell object is bound to the
> file we can then use the InvokeVerbEx method to call any of the
> commands that appear on the context menu of that file.
>
> Is that good? Of course. If you right-click a .txt file, one of the
> commands available to you is Print; if you then click Print the file
> will automatically be printed to the default printer. As we noted, the
> InvokeVerbEx method enables us to run any of the commands found on the
> context menu of a file. To call the Print command, and thus
> automatically print the file to the default printer, all we need to do
> is execute this line of code:
>
> ```
> objFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
> ```
>
> Note. What if you don’t like the way the text file prints out? In that
> case, try saving the file as temporary_print_file.htm and see if you
> like that printout any better.
>
> That’s all we need to do. Once the file has been sent to the printer
> we’re home free.
>
> Pretty cool, huh? We have to tell you, it’s scripts like this one that
> make you glad to be alive.
>
> Well, for those of you who are alive, that is.

Comment: К сожалению, это немного не то что мне нужно. У меня кнопка "Печать" находится на asp странице (на сервере) и файл который нужно печатать тоже на сервере. А hta-приложение просто у себя во фрейме открывает это приложение через ссылку. Соответственно на клиент (киоск) контент не загружается и напечатать я даже не знаю как тот файл..

Comment: т.е. киоск (локальный комп) обращается к web-серверу, который возвращает html и вы видите кнопку "печать". и когда вы ее нажимаете, что надо с сервера получить какой-то другой html и распечатать на киоске, к которому подключен принтер. я правильно понимаю?

Comment: в целом да. Только там не другой html - там rtf файл (шаблон заполненный данными)

Comment: понятно. надо скачать rtf (см. [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)), сохранить в файл и попробуйте сделать как в ответе.

Comment: спасибо большое! похоже, то что нужно) То есть главное чтобы файл, который надо напечатать выгрузился на клиент и тогда и печать будет локальная?

Comment: да, файл надо скачать на клиента.

Comment: _"похоже, то что нужно"_ -- хорошо, отметьте вопрос как принятый.